# Returning the count of relationships in neo4j cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to set the number of relationships of a particular type in a neo4j query.

For example,

A person views a number of movies and he likes a some of the moviews he has viewed.
Movie - Viewed_By -> Person
Movie - Liked_By -> Person

Movie object has a boolean field "is_liked_by" and a integer field "no_of_likes" along with other fields. The "is_liked_by" field should be true if the movie is liked by a person and the "no_of_likes" field should give the number of total likes.

Cypher to get movies viewed by a Person with name P1

```
 MATCH (m:Movie)-[r:Viewed_By]->(p:Person) WHERE p.name = 'P1' RETURN m
```

But how will I populate m.no_of_likes field in the same query ?

Also how will I populate the m.is_liked_by field ? This will have to be true if P1 likes the movie otherwise it should be false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should be what you're looking for:

```
MATCH (m:Movie)-[r:Viewed_By]->(p:Person) 
WHERE p.name = 'P1'
WITH 
   m, 
   p
RETURN
   m as movie_data,
   LENGTH(m-[:Liked_By]->(:Person)) as no_of_likes,
   EXISTS(m-[:Liked_By]->p) as is_liked_by
```

If you want it all in one data structure, you can do this (movieprop1 and movieprop2 are properties on your movie node, you can just add whatever else you want returned:

```
MATCH (m:Movie)-[r:Viewed_By]->(p:Person) 
WHERE p.name = 'P1'
WITH 
   m, 
   p
RETURN
   {
      moviefield1: m.moviefield1,
      moviefield2: m.moviefield2,
      no_of_likes: LENGTH(m-[:Liked_By]->(:Person)),
      is_liked_by: EXISTS(m-[:Liked_By]->p)
   } as movie
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works but it returns movie_data, no_of_likes and is_liked_by separately. Is it posiible to provide the no_of_likes and is_liked_by inside the movie object itself and not as separates

Comment: You can return it as one structure. I modified the answer to reflect how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

[Edited]

The data model you are describing (which seems to need a different `Movie` node instance per person for a given movie) does not work. Maintaining the  `no_of_likes` count in every `Movie` node would be a nightmare and is totally unnecessary. In fact, the `no_of_likes` and `is_liked_by` properties are both redundant -- you do not need them.

This simplified data model (without those properties) would allow multiple people to share the same `Movie` node for each movie:

```
(:Movie {name: "foo"})-[:VIEWED_BY]->(:Person {name: "bar"})
(:Movie {name: "foo"})-[:LIKED_BY]->(:Person {name: "bar"})
```

You can:

1. Get the number of likes for the movie "Elf" this way:

   ```
    MATCH (m:Movie)-[:LIKED_BY]->(:Person)
    WHERE m.name = 'Elf'
    RETURN m AS movie, COUNT(*) AS num_likes;
   ```
2. Get the number of likes for every movie (where each movie and its count will appear in a separate result row) this way:

   ```
    MATCH (m:Movie)-[:LIKED_BY]->(:Person)
    RETURN m AS movie, COUNT(*) AS num_likes;
   ```
3. Get a collection of the people who like the movie "Elf" this way:

   ```
    MATCH (m:Movie)-[:LIKED_BY]->(p:Person)
    WHERE m.name = 'Elf'
    RETURN m AS movie, COLLECT (p) AS likers;
   ```
4. Get a collection of the people who like each and every movie (in separate result rows) this way:

   ```
    MATCH (m:Movie)-[:LIKED_BY]->(p:Person)
    RETURN m AS movie, COLLECT (p) AS likers;
   ```

And you can do similar queries using the `VIEWED_BY` relationship type.

Comment: Suppose I have an application, where I can view a huge list of movies (suppose 1000). Yess, I can retrieve the list of movies with ease. But to get the number of likes for each movie i have to fire a 1000 queries (one for each movie). Similarly to get the "is_liked_by" field, I have to fire another 1000 cyphers. So there will be 2001 cyphers in total. I thought this way but it will be great if you can provide me with a good solution

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'populate the field', but with this query you can return only movies where `is_liked_by` is `true` and also return the `no_of_likes` property:

```
MATCH (m:Movie)-[r:Viewed_By]->(p:Person)
WHERE p.name = 'P1'
AND m.is_liked_by = true
RETURN DISTINCT m, m.no_of_likes
```

I think in general you should use the graph structure for your queries. `no_of_likes` is the number of relationships on a movie:

```
MATCH (m:Movie)-[r:Liked_By]->(p:Person)
RETURN m.name, count(r) as no_of_likes
```

To get all `Movies` which are liked by somebody:

```
MATCH (m:Movie)-[:Liked_By]-()
RETURN m AS movie_has_like
```

If you want to `MATCH` all movies which a `Person` viewed *and* liked (this is what your first query does I think):

```
MATCH (m:Moview)-[:Viewed_By]->(p:Person)<-[:Liked_By]-(m)
RETURN DISTINCT p, m
```

Comment: The movie object has two very specific fields, no_of_likes and is_liked_by. You have to return a list of Movie Objects viewed by Person P1. When you are returning the list, the no_of_likes field in each Movie object should contain the count of all the likes for the movie by other persons also. Again for each movie, if the user P1 has liked it then the "is_liked_by" field should be true for the objects returned

Comment: Still, you don't need the properties. What are you asking anyways?